# Unable to delete files from finder?

Tags: finder

I did option-3 on finder -> which puts the files into cascading directories mode.

Then I have selected a few files with the intention to delete them (see the screenshot).   But there is no option to 'delete' - either from popup or from menu items (see second screenshot).

[image]

[image]

Note: the files are all owned by my user as is the containing directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x  21 steboesch  wheel    714 Aug 18 15:28 util
-rw-r--r--   1 steboesch  wheel   5189 Aug 18 15:28 SqlBattery.scala
-rw-r--r--   1 steboesch  wheel   2266 Aug 18 15:28 SparkSqlQueryBenchmark.scala
-rw-r--r--   1 steboesch  wheel   3356 Aug 18 15:28 SparkSqlIgniteSql.scala
-rw-r--r--   1 steboesch  wheel   1250 Aug 18 15:28 SparkNode.scala
-rw-r--r--   1 steboesch  wheel   1433 Aug 18 15:28 SparkIgniteAbstractBenchmark.scala
-rw-r--r--   1 steboesch  wheel   1219 Aug 18 15:28 SparkDriverNode.scala
-rw-r--r--   1 steboesch  wheel   5997 Aug 18 15:28 SparkCoreRDDBenchmark.scala
-rw-r--r--   1 steboesch  wheel   1244 Aug 18 15:28 SparkBenchmarkArguments.scala
-rw-r--r--   1 steboesch  wheel   4350 Aug 18 15:28 SparkAbstractBenchmark.scala
-rw-r--r--   1 steboesch  wheel   8590 Aug 18 15:28 DataGenerator.scala
-rw-r--r--   1 steboesch  wheel   7602 Aug 18 15:28 CoreBattery.scala
drwxr-xr-x   3 steboesch  wheel    102 Aug 18 15:28 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 steboesch  wheel   2527 Aug 18 17:56 SparkIgniteSqlBenchmark.scala
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> in **Finder** changes to **Columns** view and selected files can be deleted by first moving them to the **Trash** by pressing <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> or by clicking **Move to Trash** from the **File** menu in **Finder**.

You can then empty the **Trash** by pressing:<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd>

Comment: Is is then your understanding that   the cascading view does not allow for deleting files?

Comment: @javadba, It is not called "cascading view", it's **Columns** view and files certainly can be deleted in any view in **Finder**, sans read-only media.  The image of your **Finder > File** menu shows **Move to Trash** and that's "delete", so to speak, in OS X.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. The terminology is Mac-ish: ok now I got it.